# Reading in SVM files in R (libsvm)

Tags: svm, matrix, dataset

The data files from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ are in 'svm' format.  I am trying to read this in to sparse matrix representation in R.  Is there an easy/efficient way to do this?

Here is what I am doing now: read in file line by line (800,000 lines), for each line separate classes, values, and cols.  Store the classes as a list and the features as a .csr sparse matrix (1 row), then rbind the feature row with all previous rows.

This is terribly inefficient and basically won't finish (12 minutes for 1000 lines). I think it comes from rbinding the sparse matrices once the number of rows starts to get large.

Note: the matrix (800000*48000) is too big to build and then convert to sparse format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `e1071` package has a means for exporting to the libsvm "svm" format in [the `write.svm` function](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/e1071/html/write.svm.html).  But to the best of my knowledge, there is no `read.svm` function.

Comment: Yes I found it interesting that there was a write function but no read function.  What would be ideal is if there was a read function and then you could write it as a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 10):

I found a way that is at least now feasible.

Instead of the sparseM package I use the Matrix package to build the sparse matrices.  Store the entries and columns in separate lists and then build the matrix by:

```
data=sparseMatrix(i=rep(1,length[[1]]),j=columns[[loop]],
    x=entires[[loop]],dims=c(120000,47235))
for(loop in 2:120000){
  if(loop %% 1000==0){
      print(loop)
      print(Sys.time())
  }
  data[loop,columns[[loop]]]=entries[[loop]]  
}
```

This still takes awhile (about 2 hours) but at least it works.

I store the corresponding classes in another list not in the sparse matrix.